# Spring cloud gateway always sends back HTTP status 503, how to fix it?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to use the Spring Cloud Gateway with Spring Security. But unfortunately it looks like Security does not really matters, and all of the requests are going through its destinations, or at least tries. Just tries, because I am getting HTTP status 503 every time. I am on Spring 5, and trying to be "reactive" as much as possible. What am I doing wrong? There isn't anything interesting in the log, just the usual lines, when the service tries to find the destination using Ribbon load balancing. I also enabled the access log on gateway server, hoping to have some extra info, but nothing.

I've simplified my code, and here is minimal config what doesn't work.

**POM dependencies and dependency management:**

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Cloud Gateway service -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud Eureka client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud config client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**bootstrap.yml:**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-server
  cloud:
    config:
      name: gateway-server
      username: configUser
      password: configPassword
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: config-server
eureka:  
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discUser:discPassword@localhost:9002/eureka/
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
```

**Security config:**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user1 = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("discUser")
            .password("discPassword")
            .roles("SYSTEM", "USER")
            .build();

        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user1);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        LOGGER.info("TEMP_LOG: Test");
            return http
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                    .pathMatchers("/eureka/**")
                        .hasRole("SYSTEM")
                    .pathMatchers("/eureka/css/**", "/eureka/js/**")
                        .permitAll()
                            .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Gateway route definitions:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.besztercekk.tao.gateway"})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    RouteLocator customRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, LoggingFilter loggingFilter) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route("eureka", r -> r.path("/eureka")
                .filters(f -> {
                    f.filter(loggingFilter);
                    return f;
                }).uri("lb://discovery-server:9002"))
            .build();
    }
}
```

If I call the gateway service from browser (without any user name) I'd expect a login form, or at least a 403 because I don't define the user, so security can't really do its job.

But I only get the error fallback page saying:

> Sun Mar 31 11:46:42 UTC 2019
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Service Unavailable, status=503).
>   The service or item was not found.

If I call that gateway from command line, e.g. with curl like this:

`curl --user discUser:discPassword http://localhost:8080/eureka`

then I get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Spring 6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76329284/spring-boot-3-gateway-showing-503-service-unavailable

Comment: Hi brohjoe! I have moved my stuff to Kubernetes where - in theory - I don't need the Spring Cloud Gateway. And autos service and some ingresses are doing the job. I can't emphasise enough, it's only in theory, because the ingress is only working if I address the same node where the service runs. Which kind of makes the whole ingress pointless.

Comment: Hi @bkk. The plan was to eventually move to K8s but I wanted to do local testing first.  I'm moving on to K8s now.

Comment: Hi @brohjoe! Can you please update me here how it went? Do you move to a K8S on bare metal or you use some managed solution? I am still not able to set up bare metal as I wanted. K8S nodes cannot communicate and they can’t reach each other. I turned off every firewall and network security, but it does not matter. Ingress from node A can’t talk to service on node B. Let me know if this works for you. They only can talk to the master.

Comment: I'm still in the process and I haven't done this before, so I'm in a learning phase right now.  I suggest you put in a new question.  I'll follow you to see how it goes.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi! brohjoe! I reinstalled everything, started from the OS, and it’s still the same. Does not matter if there is a firewall with opened port or no firewall at all, ingress only works when I address the pod where the service lives.I also tried a the same scenario on minikube, and it works there. But that is a bit different, you can ask for the service URL and it gives something to you. So I guess this is because of some undisclosed configuration of the pod network. Anyways, I opened some other tickets here, but nothing useful came back. Let me know how it goes for you.