# Spring boot 3 gateway showing 503 service_unavailable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, microservices

I'm getting a `NotFoundException: 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` exception in the gateway-server logs.  I'm running microservices in docker containers.  I have an `auth-service` microservice which handles authentication and Jwt. I can connect directly to the auth-service using Postman and register, validate and receive tokens via the auth-service's AuthController. However, using the gateway causes the 503 error.  Since the problem is with the gateway, I will highlight pertinent gateway code:

***SecurityConfig***

```
package com.microservices.gatewayserver.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
//Configures security settings for the gateway server. Authentication uses JWT tokens
//    for the pathMatchers and disables CSRF protection.
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers("/login-service/**").authenticated()
                        .pathMatchers("/employee-service/**").authenticated()
                        .pathMatchers("/registration-service/**").authenticated()
                        .pathMatchers("/auth-service/**").permitAll())
                        //.pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

***GatewayServerApplication***

```
package com.microservices.gatewayserver;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.annotation.LoadBalancerClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@LoadBalancerClient(name= "auth-service")
public class GatewayServerApplication {

   public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
           .getLogger(GatewayServerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServerApplication.class, args);
    }
```

***application.yml***

```
server:
  port: 8097

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: always
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: auth-service
          uri: lb://auth-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth-service/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/auth-service/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}

        - id: employee-service
          uri: lb://employee-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/employee/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/employee/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}

        - id: login-service
          uri: lb://login-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/login/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/login/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}

        - id: registration-service
          uri: lb://registration-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/registration/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/registration/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}

        - id: openapi
          uri: http://localhost:${server.port}
          predicates:
            - Path=/v3/api-docs/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/v3/api-docs/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}/v3/api-docs

  main:
    web-application-type: reactive

  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:7080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discovery-service-container:8761/eureka/

springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    urls:
      - name: auth
        url: /v3/api-docs/auth
      - name: employee
        url: /v3/api-docs/employee
      - name: login
        url: /v3/api-docs/login
      - name: registration
        url: /v3/api-docs/registration

logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}] ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} %m%n"
  level:
    springframework:
      boot:
        autoconfigure: DEBUG
    web: DEBUG
    root: DEBUG
```

***POM***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <artifactId>gateway-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <sonar.moduleKey>${project.artifactId}</sonar.moduleKey>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${micrometer-tracing.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

***Stacktrace***

```
2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/auth-service/**', method=null}
2023-05-25T05:45:20.457679873Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG Checking match of request : '/auth-service/register'; against '/auth-service/**'
2023-05-25T05:45:20.457699175Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG matched
2023-05-25T05:45:20.457742344Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG Checking authorization on '/auth-service/register' using org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$AuthorizeExchangeSpec$Access$$Lambda$648/0x00000008010ce248@1b9bc02
2023-05-25T05:45:20.458327743Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG Authorization successful
2023-05-25T05:45:20.459204178Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG Route matched: auth-service
2023-05-25T05:45:20.459229258Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG Mapping [Exchange: POST http://localhost:8097/auth-service/register] to Route{id='auth-service', uri=lb://auth-service, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/auth-service/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath /auth-service/(?<path>.*) = '/${path}'], order = 1]], metadata={}}
2023-05-25T05:45:20.459233539Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG [afe63e91-2] Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@363dab18
2023-05-25T05:45:20.459345964Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG Sorted gatewayFilterFactories: [[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@6a74d228}, order = -2147483648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@720653c2}, order = -2147482648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@36bc415e}, order = -1], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@3e134896}, order = 0], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter@2e3a5237}, order = 0], [[RewritePath /auth-service/(?<path>.*) = '/${path}'], order = 1], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@349d0836}, order = 10000], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter@301d8120}, order = 10150], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.LoadBalancerServiceInstanceCookieFilter@6d367020}, order = 10151], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@72ba28ee}, order = 2147483646], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@72458efc}, order = 2147483647], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@6a714237}, order = 2147483647]]
2023-05-25T05:45:20.460796164Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] - WARN No servers available for service: auth-service
2023-05-25T05:45:20.461939954Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG [afe63e91-2] Resolved [NotFoundException: 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE "Unable to find instance for auth-service"] for HTTP POST /auth-service/register
2023-05-25T05:45:20.462477063Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG [afe63e91-2] Encoding [{timestamp=Thu May 25 05:45:20 GMT 2023, path=/auth-service/register, status=503, error=Service Unav (truncated)...]
2023-05-25T05:45:20.467139970Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG [afe63e91-2, L:/172.27.0.9:8097 - R:/172.27.0.1:58344] Decreasing pending responses, now 0
2023-05-25T05:45:20.468226365Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG [afe63e91-2] Completed 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
2023-05-25T05:45:20.468294940Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG [afe63e91-2, L:/172.27.0.9:8097 - R:/172.27.0.1:58344] Last HTTP response frame
```

Comment: How are you running the Docker containers?

Comment: The request to `auth-server` looks to be resolved correctly but `auth-server` seems to be having some issues handling the request `/auth-service/register`. Maybe verify the logs of the `auth-server` to see if there are any errors.

Comment: If I use Postman to connect to the auth-server at port 9898, I can reach auth-service/register just fine.  I really don't understand the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a service discovery like netflix eureka to register your applications like auth service in this service and gateway can find auth service by name ->

> routes:
> - id: auth-service
> uri: lb://auth-service
> predicates:
> - Path=/auth-service/**
> filters:
> - RewritePath=/auth-service/(?.*), /${path}

I think maybe somehow if you define DNS in your docker and setting the auth service name to the auth service ip and port no need to using discovery service

Comment: I have eureka discovery microservice running on port 8761.

Comment: in your configs if you are connecting to localhost:8761 it cannot register your endpoint services in eureka because your application is in own container and in its container there is not any eureka application

Comment: I'm looking at all of my microservices in Eureka server at localhost:8761 in the browser.

Comment: This issue is simular to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441792/spring-cloud-gateway-always-sends-back-http-status-503-how-to-fix-it?noredirect=1#comment134717116_55441792  I'm moving on to Kubernetes where spring gateway is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

according to this tip

```
2023-05-25T05:45:20.461939954Z 2023-05-25 05:45:20 [,] -DEBUG [afe63e91-2] Resolved [NotFoundException: 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE "Unable to find instance for auth-service"] for HTTP POST /auth-service/register
```

You can try these methods

1. Check your eureka, does the eureka service have the same name as the gateway route?
2. Check if your docker exposes the port?
3. Your gateway is running in docker, so your routing address cannot be 127.0.0.1 or localhost, but should be an ip address of an intranet or public network

Comment: When running services in docker containers, a port is exposed for the localhost as well as an internal docker port.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I've solved by simply adding the server context path to the service name you've provided in your yaml. I'm pretty sure that you, like me, have forgotten to insert the server context path of the authentication service.
So suppose your auth service acts at context path "/auth", then you need to modify your gateway configuration like below

```
lb://auth-service/auth
```

This happens because eureka service registers only the host (localhost in this case) and the port the service is listening to. So basically, you are sending your requests to the wrong path, that's the reason why you are getting NotFound

Answer (score 0):

bro.

You can try changing spring cloud gateway maven dependency to this way.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>${VERSION}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

remove the

```
- RewritePath=/auth-service/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
```

and add a - StripPrefix=1 and you will be able to access your service

or else you should redirect

```
RewritePath=/auth-service/( ?<path>. *), /oauth/token/$\{path}
```

/oauth/token is the default oauth url

I hope to help you